# If lota drops of water drop on your clothes, does it make clothes impure?

Tags: salat, clothing, self-purification

Many asian muslims use [lota(vessel)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lota_(vessel)) to wash their private parts. When I fill it up, the water run downs the outside and while washing the drops from outside drop on the under garments, this has lead a confusion of if the clothes are pure or impure.

The Lota is always on the floor of the toilet.

is my clothes impure and if I put my pants back on with those drops, do I need to take ghusl?

Comment: Water by default is tahir mutahhir in fiqh: clean and cleaning. Only if there's clear sign oif najasah and the najasah appears in a huge amount this might change the overall view. From what you say there's no reasoin as to why oen would even think of this vessel containing najis water.

Comment: @Sassir just had a word with my wife, she said, if the water was inside vessel n dropped onto the clothes, then it will make clothes impure, it water is from outside it mean water wasn't impure so clothes will be ok.  I need to confirm this.

Comment: As long as what inside the vessel is only water or mainly water -and it has no attribute of uncleanness:color,odor, taste- it is clean.